# Помогите с Youtube api

Tags: android, java

Столкнулся с вот такой проблемой, никак не могу ее решить, помогите, плизз:

```
public class Risunok_page11 extends Fragment implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

    public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
                                        boolean wasRestored) {
        if (!wasRestored) {
            player.cueVideo(VIDEO_ID);
        }
    } 
    public static final String API_KEY = "MyKey";
    public static final String VIDEO_ID = "o7VVHhK9zf0";
    private TextView text;
    public Risunok_page11() {}

    public final static String TAG = Risunok_page11.class.getSimpleName();
    public static Risunok_page11 newInstance() {
        return new Risunok_page11();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.risunok_page11_layout , container, false);

        text=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.webtextview1);

        ConnectivityManager cn =(ConnectivityManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo nf=cn.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if(nf != null && nf.isConnected()==true )
        {
            YouTubePlayerFragment youTubePlayerFragment = (YouTubePlayerFragment) getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtubeplayerfragment);
            youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(API_KEY, this);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.not_internet_please, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            text.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "KShYJgLB.ttf"));
            text.setText(R.string.not_internet);
        }

        return rootView;

    }
    public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider,
                                        YouTubeInitializationResult result) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                       "onInitializationFailure()", 
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private Context getApplicationContext() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

В лайауте вот что:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"       
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/LayoutHome1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff">

    <fragment 
    android:id="@+id/youtubeplayerfragment" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_weight="0.02" 
    class="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment" />

 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/webtextview1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="40sp"/> 
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Ошибка по стектрейсу вот:

> 01-29 01:29:44.749 1818 1818 E  
> AndroidRuntime                      
> FATAL EXCEPTION: main 01-29
> 01:29:44.749 1818 1818 E  
> AndroidRuntime                      
> Process: by.sviter.allbestlessons,
> PID: 1818 01-29 01:29:44.749 1818 1818
> E     AndroidRuntime                
> android.view.InflateException: Binary
> XML file line #26: Error inflating
> class fragment 01-29 01:29:44.749 1818
> 1818 E     AndroidRuntime           
> at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
> 01-29 01:29:44.749 1818 1818 E  
> AndroidRuntime                      
> at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
> 01-29 01:29:44.749 1818 1818 E  
> AndroidRuntime                      
> at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
> 01-29 01:29:44.749 1818 1818 E  
> AndroidRuntime                      
> at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
> 01-29 01:29:44.749 1818 1818 E  
> AndroidRuntime                      
> at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
> 01-29 01:29:44.749 1818 1818 E  
> AndroidRuntime                      
> at
> by.sviter.allbestlessons.risunok_item.Risunok_page11.onCreateView(Risunok_page11.java:41) 01-29 01:29:44.749 1818 1818 E  
> AndroidRuntime                      
> at
> android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
> 01-29 01:29:44.749 1818 1818 E  
> AndroidRuntime                      
> at
> android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
> 01-29 01:29:44.749 1818 1818 E  
> AndroidRuntime                      
> at
> android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
> 01-29 01:29:44.749 1818 1818 E  
> AndroidRuntime                      
> at
> android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
> 01-29 01:29:44.749 1818 1818 E  
> AndroidRuntime                      
> at
> android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
> 01-29 01:29:44.749 1818 1818 E  
> AndroidRuntime                      
> at
> android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
> 01-29 01:29:44.749 1818 1818 E  
> AndroidRuntime                      
> at
> android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
> 01-29 01:29:44.749 1818 1818 E  
> AndroidRuntime                      
> at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
> 01-29 01:29:44.749 1818 1818 E  
> AndroidRuntime                      
> at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
> 01-29 01:29:44.749 1818 1818 E  
> AndroidRuntime                      
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
> 01-29 01:29:44.749 1818 1818 E  
> AndroidRuntime                      
> at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native
> Method) 01-29 01:29:44.749 1818 1818 E
> AndroidRuntime                      
> at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
> 01-29 01:29:44.749 1818 1818 E  
> AndroidRuntime                      
> at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
> 01-29 01:29:44.749 1818 1818 E  
> AndroidRuntime                      
> at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
> 01-29 01:29:44.749 1818 1818 E  
> AndroidRuntime                      
> Caused by:
> java.lang.ClassCastException:
> com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment
> cannot be cast to
> android.support.v4.app.Fragment 01-29
> 01:29:44.749 1818 1818 E  
> AndroidRuntime                      
> at
> android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:402)
> 01-29 01:29:44.749 1818 1818 E  
> AndroidRuntime                      
> at
> android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:377)
> 01-29 01:29:44.749 1818 1818 E  
> AndroidRuntime                      
> at
> android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:277)
> 01-29 01:29:44.749 1818 1818 E  
> AndroidRuntime                      
> at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
> 01-29 01:29:44.749 1818 1818 E  
> AndroidRuntime                      
> ... 19 more

Comment: @sviter-pro, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Мой магический шар навёл меня на подозрение, что дело всё в XML, где странное значение веса во фрагменте тыТрубы:

> android:layout_weight="0.02"

И в нём же нема высоты, а следующий TextView на всё пространство претендует. Да и один из LinearLayout явно лишний. И фрагменты лучше из кода добавлять, а не из XML.

В общем надо пересмотреть лэйаут.

Comment: ага, еще у фрагмента высота не задана, а еще нужно поменять class на name